# How to regroup in django template using foreign key

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to display a list of ingredients grouped by category. I got as far as displaying a list of category ids but I can't seem to move forward with this. Here is my setup, any help is much appreciated.

```
# models.py
class IngredienceCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Ingredience(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    category = models.ForeignKey(IngredienceCategory, null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


# views.py
def home(request):
    ingredients = Ingredience.objects.all()
    ingrcat = IngredienceCategory.objects.all()

    return render_to_response('home.html', {'ingredients': ingredients, 'ingrcat': ingrcat,})


# home.html template
<h2>List of items by category:</h2>
{% regroup ingredients|dictsort:"category_id" by category_id as ingr_by_cats %}
{% for category in ingr_by_cats %}
    <p>{{ category.grouper }}</p>
    <ul>
        {% for item in ingrcat.list %}
            <li><a href="#" id="{{ item.id }}">{{ item.name }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

What I'm currently getting:

```
<h2>List of items by category:</h2>
<p>1</p>
<ul></ul>

<p>2</p>
<ul></ul>

<p>3</p>
<ul></ul>
```

What I'm trying to achieve:

```
<h2>List of items by category:</h2>
<p>Category A</p>
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>

<p>Category B/p>
<ul>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
</ul>

<p>Category C</p>
<ul>
    <li>Item 7</li>
    <li>Item 8</li>
    <li>Item 9</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
{% for item in ingrcat.list %}
```

You should have:

```
{% for item in category.list %}
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, that solves one half of my problem, the items are now getting displayed. Another issue I'm having is how to display category name instead of category id.

Comment: Regroup by `category` instead of `category_id`, then your `grouper` will be an instance of `Category` and you can access all the attributes on it as normal.